# Python Neural Network Reinforcement Learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, reinforcement-learning

I want to make a Neural Network that is trained using reinforcement learning in python.

```
X -> [ANN] -> yEstimate -> score! -> (repeat until weights are optimised)
```

I'm using Scikit-learn at the moment but there doesn't seem to be all the neural networks stuff tries to fit `yEstimate` to `yTarget`.

Are there secrets to scikit-learn or are there other libraries that I don't know about for accomplishing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google TensorFlow is one big library with a Python interface for the creation of neural networks. See https://github.com/nivwusquorum/tensorflow-deepq for more information and examples about reinforcement learning.

Answer (score 3):

Here you have an example http://pybrain.org/

Here another https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Reinforcement-Learning-Toolkit/1.0

There are many research groups in robotics using reinforcement learning. If you don't like the ones that I gave you, you can try to look in these groups